# xpath can't find anything in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

UPDATE 2 - adding `before(:each)` block

```
before(:each) do
    ...
    post_via_redirect(
        sub_domain(
            path: login_view_path(
                @p
            ), 
            subdomain: @account.subdomain
        ),
        first_name: "Capybara",
        last_name: "RSpec"
    )

    expect(response).to render_template(:show)
end
```

---

UPDATE

`response.body` has the data I'm looking for
but `page.html` only has a doctype.

---

ORIGINAL

I'm trying to do some integration testing. I have this:

```
require "spec_helper"

feature "Tracking without Javascript" do
    ...
    scenario "when navigating to a content" do
        ...
        # this passes so I know there is a body
        expect(response.body).to include(c.name)

        find(:xpath, "/html") # see if xpath works...
    end
end
```

and I get the error:

```
 Failure/Error: find(:xpath, "/html")
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find xpath "/html"
```

any ideas?

Comment: Which kind of spec is this? If you haven't configured it differently, it should be which directory is it in. I ask because `response` isn't something I have a lot of experience with in Capybara, and the [docs](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/tree/2.1.0#gotchas) say "Access to response is limited. Some drivers allow access to response headers and HTTP status code, but this kind of functionality is not provided by some drivers, such as Selenium."

Comment: lemme add my before block

Answer (score 0):

`post_via_redirect` doesn't involve Capybara - that directly (more-or-less) interacts with Rails, but not through a browser. That would be why Capybara never points an actual page.

**Original (misguided) answer for posterity:**

If you are using the newest versions of everything, then Capybara will not find invisible elements by default. Could you try `find(:xpath, "/html", visible: false)` and see if that works? The other thing I can think of is that your XPath may not be matching as you expect. Try `//html` instead.

On the meta level, you'll almost never see this kind of assertion, as the end-user doesn't care if you have an `html` element or not. You will get more useful tests by checking for things that the user can see. I also prefer to use CSS selectors, as other things (JavaScript and CSS) tend to care about them as well. Our whole test suite has maybe one or two XPath selectors for very ugly cases.

Comment: Actually I take this back. I just ran Capybara locally, and `find(:xpath, '/html')` worked just fine against the Google home page. Perhaps you can update your question with the output of `page.html`?

Comment: I've updated my question. page.html is pretty much empty, whereas response.body has what page.html should. :-\

Comment: I have an `xpath: "//li[contains(text(), 'You did not provide any details for authentication.')]"` using the `expect` if this element present, then it should return `true`. could you pls help me to solve this using `RSpec`.